# Setting local notifications on all devices Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, icloud

I have added date triggered local notifications to my app and now I want the user to be able to get the notification they set on one device on all of their devices that have the app. I save the notification they set in a core data entity (saving the notifcation identifier and date it's suppose to be triggered). The app uses a NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to sync the users devices together.

**Since I save the notifications the user sets to this iCloud container, is there a way I can listen to iCloud changes in the app's background so when a notification is added in iCloud, I can read it and set it as a local notification on their other devices?**

I was able to do this when the app is in the foreground with `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(type(of: self).storeRemoteChange(_:)), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)` in my core data manager file. But I would like to do this when the app is not opened at all.

You can think of this as a user setting a reminder in the Apple reminders app and how that notification pops up on all of my iCloud devices at the time I set it at. I prefer to not make any type server to handle this because I am not familiar with using servers.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You would need to use remote push notifications from a server to all devices where the user has logged into their account. Local notifications are just that; local

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks you for the fast response. Is there a way to do it with any of Apple's services? This app already uses iCloud and bringing in a separate server to handle notifications seems like a lot. There is no login with a server, and the only thing that links all the devices together is iCloud

Comment: Well, you could synchronise the users data via CloudKit or similar and use the sync notification to schedule a corresponding local notification

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 I made a Core data entity where I can save the user's local notification to it. Now it just seems like I have to listen for the iCloud changes in the background of the app on my other devices, but I can not seem to figure out how to do this. I am new to using iCloud and can not find any resources about listening for changes. Please let me know if you know how to do this!

Comment: You need to use CloudKit, not Core Data, unless you have used the new CloudKit backing store for Core Data that is available in iOS 13....

Comment: I do use the new Cloudkit backing store for Core Data (`NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`). That's why I added notifications to Core data because the app already syncs with other user devices

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe that using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` provides access to the cloud kit sync push notification. Generally this is a good thing as it simplifies your implementation. In this case, however, you want to use this notification for background execution. As I see it you have three options: 1. Use native CloudKit for this 2. Schedule local notifications on the device when your app comes to the foreground (this means that new notifications may not be scheduled if the user doesn't run your app on that device) 3. Use push notifications from a server.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was able to achieve the second option with `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. I still need to get these notifications in the background, what in native CloudKit would be helpful for this?